# Edit and delete objects via template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make an edit/delete records page for my project whereby the user can select check boxes allowing them to edit or delete multiple records in the database. I'm not really sure where to begin so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what do really want to do ?

Comment: Create a template that shows all of the records whilst allowing the user to tick a checkbox next to each record. They can then select whether to edit or delete the specific record. Sorry I'm not the best at this as you can probably tell

Comment: ahhh ok ! like django admin ?

Comment: Yeah exactly like django admin. Wasn't very clear :)

Comment: You want many things: 1) deletion: you want a view and a template, a forms to display and mini js code to toggle many checkbox in list result; 2) Edition: I you want to edit many object in same time the best way is to use formset the end of this like 1) or if you want to edit single object you want to create a form, view and template.